# How do I make a button invisible but active in PyGTK?

Tags: python, button, pygtk

As far as I know, `hide()` and `set_visible(False)` both make the button invisible and inactive. Any workaround?

Comment: It does not make logic... why do you want an invisible button to be active?

Comment: I have a graphic and I want the graphic to be clickable. For example, clicking at the head of the person is one command, and clicking at the stomach of the person is another command. Nevertheless, if this is still not logical, please tell me if it is possible.

Comment: If invisibility is not possible, how about transparency?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'workaround', and that is changing the implementation strategy. The idea of a clickable graphic seems legit, but I wouldn't recommend mixing custom 2D drawing and widgets.

- If it fits your needs, you can split the graphic of a person up and put specific parts like the head image on a button. Have a look at [`gtk_button_set_image`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-image) and its Python equivalent.
- Another possibility is to bind a click event to the image and to query the x/y coordinates of the click. Simplest math, just iterate through a list of shapes associated with the image and determine a list of matching shapes (e.g. (50/100) is within the rectangle with the upper left corner of (30/80) and width & height of 40, this must be the stomach region).